# Give example to load js, css and images in small spring application

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm struggling to load js, css, and images in a small spring application application. After a lot R&D still I'm not able to load js, css and images. can any body give me small working example to load js, css and images in spring. Please help me i already have wasted alot time on it and haven't get anything. I'm using spring 3.0.xsd version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know structure of simple web-application, keep use the same for structure for Spring-MVC project also.

You have to give link to your CSS, JS and images paths to include in you HTML/JSP page like below:

```
<LINK href="<%=contextPath%>/pages/css/cssfile_name.css" type=text/css
    rel=stylesheet>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=contextPath%>/pages/js/your_js.js"></script>
```

Keep your static content in WEB-INF. Checkout here:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project structure. The simplest way to get a working example is the following:

- Install [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all)
- File -> New -> Spring Project -> Template "Spring MVC Project"
- Put your CSS and JavaScript files in `src/main/webapp/resources`

Now you can reference your files in your JSP's (in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views`) like this:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/my-script-file.js" />" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/my-style-file.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```